# How can I put my <h1> element beneath my image?

Tags: css, image, text

I'm having an issue with [my layout](http://lrroberts0122.github.com/DWS/lab4/index.html), where I have an `<h1>` element sitting above an image. Circumstances make me unable to edit the HTML, so how can I position the `<h1>` element *beneath* the image?

**My code looks like this:**

```
<h1>Razer Press Release</h1>
<img src="/images/trongamingkeyboard.jpg" />
```

But basically, in the link, you can see the "Razer Press Release" text that I would like moved directly beneath the image. I just don't know how!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you edit the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS to swap the vertical positions of the two elements.

```
<h1 style="position: relative; top: 500px;">Razer Press Release</h1>
<img style="position: relative; top: -18px;" src="/images/trongamingkeyboard.jpg" />
```

If you can't use inline styles (which is simplest) these selectors will work, given the markup in that page:

```
#cta > h1:first-child {
    position: relative;
    top: 500px;
}

#cta > h1:first-child + div > img {
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML

```
<section id="cta">
  <h1>Razer Press Release</h1>
  <div>
    <img alt="Photograph of the new Tron Gaming Keyboard by Razer" src="images/tron-keyboard-main.jpg">
  </div>
</section>
```

My CSS

```
#cta {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

#cta h1{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 20px; /* your placement */
  left: 20px; /* your placement */
}
```